# Can't get app.post(...) to work in NodeJs (Express)

Tags: node.js

I know this may be a redundant question, but I am asking it after much research. I am trying to accept html form data and print it using Node server. I can't get it to work on post method. Below are the source code files:

**HTML Form:**

```
<form action="/submit-data" method="post">
    First Name: <input name="firstName" type="text" /> <br />
    Last Name: <input name="lastName" type="text" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.post('/submit-data', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.body.firstName + ' ' + req.body.lastName;

    res.send(name + ' Submitted Successfully!');
});

var server = app.listen(7777, function () {
    console.log('Node server is running..');
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "nodePost",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "connect": "^3.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.4.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

But when I run the whole thing, it gives me a 404 response on submitting the form:

Please show me the way. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where's the route that serves the html form? It would need to be on the same `domain/protocol/port` for `/submit-data` to point to the correct location.

Comment: "form.html" and "server.js" are both in the same folder.

Comment: It seems like you're serving `form.html` from a different web server (e.g. Apache), since your Express server is not set up to serve static files currently. This is what @KevinB is saying. You're probably navigating to `http://server/form.html`, but then your form submits to your other webserver at `http://server/submit-data` instead of the Express server at `http://express-server:7777/submit-data`.

Comment: Also, you should not be putting your node.js code in a place that's publicly accessible from another web server, otherwise all of your code is open to everyone (potentially exposing vulnerabilities and/or leaking sensitive information).

Comment: I am using localhost. So to run the html file, I use "http://localhost:7777/nodePost/form.html", and on submitting, the url bar shows "http://localhost:7777/submit-data". And ther's no other server running. 

Also, when I type the app.post(..) command in my IDE, it underlines it and indicates it as an "Unresolved method or function".

Comment: Right, but, how does /nodePost/form.html work? are you using apache/nginx and a reverse proxy? i assume your ide just doesn't understand `require('express')`

Comment: I am using IntelliJ(Ultimate Edition). It provides the templates and server configuration readily.

Comment: I am pretty sure no other server is needed, because the following code works perfectly:

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(7777);
console.log("Server is running...");

P.S. I have created the onRequest handler method.

Comment: Your code should work as-is. The fact that it isn't points out that the problem must be somewhere else. That is why i'm asking for information about "somewhere else." If you had nothing else interacting with what you currently have, you would get a 404 when you visit `http://localhost:7777/nodePost/form.html`. The fact that you aren't suggests that either the code you provided is incomplete, or there is a second webserver involved.

Comment: what about app.post being indicated as unresolved ? Moreover other http methods like app.delete(), app.put(), etc. are also giving the "unresolved" error. Only app.get() is working !!!

Comment: No, I am getting a 404 response on the URL ""localhost:7777/submit-data". @KevinB

Comment: You'll have to ask your IDE that. Not all predictions with autocomplete are correct or make sense.

Comment: @VatsalGosaliya Yes, that's my point. Since the form.html isn't giving you a 404, you must not be giving us the full picture.

Comment: @KevinB This is all there is. I have just started learning Node and this is my first attempt at processing form data.

Comment: nothing in your node server code serves a form.html

Comment: Look, first I type "http:localhost:7777/nodePost/form.html" which gives me the form.

Then before filling the form, I go to my IDE and execute "server.js". The console shows the message "Node server is running..."

Then back to chrome, I fill the form and hit submit. It redirects to "http:localhost:7777/submit-data", where I can see the 404 message.

Comment: exactly, that's my point. Something other than node is serving form.html. How is node possibly running on port 7777 if something else already is? I could understand it if you were proxying it through another webserver, but you haven't provided that in your question either. there's too many moving  parts that could be affecting this that you aren't providing.

Comment: It's been solved. Was an issue of conflicting ports.